# Markov Chain: Calculating Expectation Reach a Certain Set of States

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose I have a Markov chain $Z_k$ with $6$ states, as depicted below: 
[image]

The probability of moving from one node to a neighboring node is $1/2$. For example, the probability of moving from node $1$ to node $2$ is $1/2$ and the probability of moving from node $1$ to node $6$ is $1/2$ etc.
Suppose $P(Z_0=1)=1$. That is we start state $1$. We need to compute two things:

1. Compute the expected time we first reach the bottom of our pyramid (states $3$, $4$, or $5$). That is compute $E[T_B]$ where $T_B=min\{j: Z_j \in \{3,4,5\}\}$

My attempt: I try listing out all the possibilities
I can go from:

1. I can go from State $1-2-3$. Time is $2$ when base is reached and probability $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$
2. $1-2-1-2-3$. Time is $4$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{16}$.
3. $1-2-1-2-1-2-3$. Time is $6$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{64}$
4. $1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2-3$. Time is $8$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{64}$.
   etc...
   Thus my conclusion for these types of sequences expected value is:

$2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}+ 4*\frac{1}{16}+6*\frac{1}{64}+8*\frac{1}{256}  ...$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{2k}=\frac{8}{9}$

5. Now, I can also go from State $1-6-5$. Time is $2$ when base is reached and probability $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$
6. $1-6-1-6-5$. Time is $4$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{16}$.
7. $1-6-1-6-1-6-5$. Time is $6$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{64}$
8. $1-6-1-6-1-6-1-6-5$. Time is $8$ when base is reached. Probability of occurring is $\frac{1}{64}$.

Thus my conclusion for these types of sequences expected value is:

$2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}+ 4*\frac{1}{16}+6*\frac{1}{64}+8*\frac{1}{256}  ...$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{2k}=\frac{8}{9}$

But there are more possibilities:

8. $1-2-1-6-5.$ The time is $4$ probability $1/16$
9. $1-2-1-6-1-6-5$. The time is $6$ probability $1/64$

10.$1-2-1-6-1-6-1-6-5 etc..$. The time is $8$ with probability $1/256$.

$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 2k \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{2k}=\frac{7}{18}$

Still more possibilities....:
Too many possibilities (unfortunately gave up) as its like the Markov Chain restarts when we go back to $1$. Couldn't figure it out. Please let me know what I should do and thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$, let $m_i = E(T_B | Z_t = i)$ be the expected number of steps until reaching $\{3,4,5\}$, starting from state $i$.  Trivially, $m_3=m_4=m_5=0$.
To obtain a system of linear constraints, apply first-step analysis (conditioning on the first step out of state $i$).  For $i=1$, we have
\begin{align}
m_1 &= \sum_{j\in\{2,6\}} E(T_B | Z_t = 1, Z_{t+1} = j) P(Z_{t+1} = j | Z_t=1)\\
&= \sum_{j\in\{2,6\}} (1 + E(T_B | Z_{t+1} = j)) \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\in\{2,6\}} 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j\in\{2,6\}} E(T_B | Z_{t+1} = j) \\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\in\{2,6\}} m_j.
\end{align}
For $i=2$, we have
\begin{align}
m_2 &= \sum_{j\in\{1,3\}} E(T_B | Z_t = 2, Z_{t+1} = j) P(Z_{t+1} = j | Z_t=2) \\
&= \sum_{j\in\{1,3\}} (1 + E(T_B | Z_{t+1} = j)) \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j\in\{1,3\}} 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j\in\{1,3\}} E(T_B | Z_{t+1} = j) \\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\in\{1,3\}} m_j\\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2}(m_1+0).
\end{align}
The $i=6$ case is similar. So we obtain the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
m_1 &= 1 + (m_2+m_6)/2 \\
m_2 &= 1 + m_1/2 \\
m_6 &= 1 + m_1/2
\end{align}
By substituting the last two constraints into the first one, we obtain
$$m_1 = 1 + (1 + m_1/2 + 1 + m_1/2)/2 = 2 + m_1/2,$$
which implies that $m_1 = 4$.

Comment: Hi @Rob Pratt I'm a bit confused. How do you get $m_1=1+(m_2+m+6)/2$, can't seem to follow.

Comment: I just updated the answer with more details.

Comment: why @Robert Pratt in the second sum is j in {3,6}, I thought that from 2 you can go to either 1 or 3. Also i don't get in the second sum how you get from the sum that m2=1+1/2(0+m6). I'm having a really hard time following.

Comment: I initially had a typo and then corrected it. Refresh the answer to see the correct indices.

Comment: I don't understand how the sum implies 1+1/2(m1+0). Where do you get this from/could you explain it in words as maybe it will be easier for me to understand? Thanks

Comment: And how does it follow in the first sum that m1=1+1/2 sum mj. I don't understand the last steps of each of the two demonstrations

Comment: The 1 comes from $1/2+1/2$.  The rest comes from applying the definition of $m_j$.

Comment: Hi @Rob Pratt honestly very sorry to bother you but where do you get 1/2+1/2=1. You have sum from j=1,3 1/2 +1/2 E(TB|Zt+1=j). how does this equal 1+1/2(m1+0). could you explain in words or write in more steps as I'm not sure how the one is coming from 1/2+1/2. I don't see how you get two 1/2 and right now its difficult for me to follow anything, so I would appreciate it if you could explain it more as I just want to understand the concept better

Comment: I added a couple more steps to the answer.

Comment: @Robb Pratt thanks its clearer now

Answer (score 2):

Taking two steps in the Markov chain can lead to one of two things, with equal probability:

- $1 \to 2 \to 3$ or $1 \to 6 \to 5$ and we're done.
- $1 \to 2 \to 1$ or $1 \to 6 \to 1$ and we're back where we started.

We took $2$ steps. In the first case, we have $0$ steps left, and in the second case, we have $\mathbb E[T_B]$ more steps left in expectation. Therefore 
$$
   \mathbb E[T_B] = 2 + \frac12 (0 + \mathbb E[T_B])
$$
and, solving, $\mathbb E[T_B] = 4$.

Comment: makes perfect sense thanks. So i'm guessing it is impossible to do it my method

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's more work. The key would be noticing that all paths to the bottom of length $2k$ have the form $$1 \to a_1 \to 1 \to a_2 \to 1 \to \dots \to 1 \to a_k \to b$$ where $a_1, \dots, a_k \in \{2,6\}$ and $b$ is the other neighbor of $a_k$, and there are exactly $2^k$ such paths.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach in the spirit of your initial attempt, you can condition on the number $2k$ of steps to reach $\{3,4,5\}$ from $1$:
\begin{align}
E(T_B) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2k\ P(\text{$2k$ steps}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2k\ 2^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-1/2)^2} \\
&= 4
\end{align}

Comment: why is P(2k steps)=2^k(1/2)^2k

Comment: There are $2^k$ paths of length $2k$ from 1 to $\{3,4,5\}$, and each of the $2k$ steps has probability $1/2$.

Comment: I think I see because there are 2^k sample paths?

Comment: Yes, the $2^k$ paths described by @Misha Lavrov.