# How long will it take to visit each city in order for Travelling Salesperson?

Tags: probability

This is a modification of the Travelling Salesperson Problem: Suppose we have 5 cities and there is a probability of going from any city to any other city (i.e. a Markov Chain):

[image]

I tried to represent this scenario using the R programming language:

```
set.seed(123)

transition_matrix <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

for(i in 1:5) {
    transition_matrix[i,] <- runif(5)
    transition_matrix[i,] <- transition_matrix[i,] / sum(transition_matrix[i,])
}
```

The corresponding Markov Chain for this problem looks like this:

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.08692491 0.23827784 0.12361982 0.2669061 0.28427129
[2,] 0.01841313 0.21345092 0.36070003 0.2228803 0.18455562
[3,] 0.34626521 0.16405558 0.24520376 0.2072284 0.03724707
[4,] 0.36424312 0.09961467 0.01702542 0.1327401 0.38637668
[5,] 0.22968745 0.17888838 0.16538491 0.2567298 0.16930943
```

I am trying to solve the following problem:

- Problem 1: Given that we start in a random city, how long would it take on average to visit all cities at least once?
- Problem 2: Given that we start in a random city, how long would it take on average to visit all cities in order for the first time (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5)?

I wrote two simulations in R to answer these questions by simulation : Simply simulate the random paths in the Markov Chain until the condition is met - count how long it took and then repeat multiple times:

```
#problem 1
num_steps <- numeric(1000)

# Repeat  1000 times
for(j in 1:1000) {
    # Initialize the state vector
    state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = rep(0.2, 5))
    
    # initialize a vector to keep track of visited states
    visited_states <- rep(FALSE, 5)
    
    # Initialize  counter
    iterations <- 0
    
    # first while
    while(!all(visited_states)) {
        # current
        visited_states[state] <- TRUE
        
        # Transition
        state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix[state,])
        
        # Increment tcounter
        iterations <- iterations + 1
    }
    
    # Record the number of steps 
    num_steps[j] <- iterations
}

print(num_steps)
num_steps1 = num_steps

# problem 2

num_steps <- numeric(1000)


for(j in 1:1000) {
    
    state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = rep(0.2, 5))
    
 
    path <- numeric(0)
    
    
    iterations <- 0
    
    # simulate until states 1,2,3,4,5 are visited in order
    while(TRUE) {
     
        path <- c(path, state)
        
        state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix[state,])
        
        iterations <- iterations + 1
        
        # termination condition for while statement
        if(length(path) >= 5 && all(tail(path, 5) == 1:5)) {
            break
        }
    }
    
    
    num_steps[j] <- iterations
}

print(num_steps)
num_steps2 = num_steps
```

The final answers look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
mean1 <- mean(num_steps1)
mean2 <- mean(num_steps2)

p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = num_steps1), aes(x)) + theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_density(color = "blue") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean1), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = paste("Distribution for the Number of Visits to Reach All States (1000 Simulations)"),
         subtitle = paste("Average number of visits:", round(mean1, 2)))

p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = num_steps2), aes(x)) + theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_density(color = "blue") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean2), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = paste("Distribution for the Number of Visits to Reach All States in Order (1000 Simulations)"),
         subtitle = paste("Average number of visits:", round(mean2, 2)))
```

[image]

I tried to find a mathematical way (i.e. non-simulation) to solve this problem but the closest thing I could find was: [Markov Chain: Calculating Expectation Reach a Certain Set of States](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386266/markov-chain-calculating-expectation-reach-a-certain-set-of-states)

Can someone please show me how approaches discussed here ([Markov Chain: Calculating Expectation Reach a Certain Set of States](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386266/markov-chain-calculating-expectation-reach-a-certain-set-of-states)) can be adapted to answer arbitrary conditions (e.g. visiting all states in order, visiting all states backwards, etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a demonstration of how, were probabilities from one state to another (including itself) uniform at $\frac15$ each, the problem can be solved.
With varying probabilities, the same *process* can be adopted, but of course, appropriate probabilities would need to be inserted, and computerisation of computations would obviously be needed.

$\mathtt{Problem\; One}$

Any of the cities could be the starting one, call it $s$ (four cities left to cover) and label *states* $a,b,c,d$ (representing $3,2,1,0$ cities left to cover)

At the beginning, she is at $s$. From there, with one step, either she remains where she was with probability $\frac15$ or moves to an uncovered city with probability $\frac45$ This is expressed in equation $1$. From $a$ (where she has covered two cities and has $3$ left to cover, we similarly get equation $2$, and so on and so forth.

Then proceeding step by step, we get the equations

$s = 1 + s/5 + 4a/5 \tag 1$
$a = 1 + 2a/5 +3b/5 \tag 2$
$b = 1 + 3b/5 +2c/5 \tag 3$
$c = 1 +  4c/5  \tag4$
[From $c$, with one step, we either revert to $a$ with $Pr=\frac45$ or reach the end, $d$]

[Solving](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s+%3D+1+%2B+s%2F5+%2B+4a%2F5%2C+a+%3D+1+%2B+2a%2F5+%2B3b%2F5%2C+b+%3D+1+%2B+3b%2F5+%2B2c%2F5%2C+c+%3D+1+%2B++4c%2F5++) the above set of equations, I get $s = \Large\frac{125}{12}$

$\mathtt{Problem\; Two}$

From the wording, it appears that you want a **straight** $12345$ sequence at some point

Defining the states
$s:\;$  starting (nothing achieved)
$a:\;$  $1$ achieved
$b:\;$  $12$ in sequence achieved
$c:\;$  $123$ in sequence achieved
$d:\;$  $1234$ in sequence achieved
$e:\;$  $12345$ in sequence achieved

The state equations are then

$s = 1+a/5+4s/5 \tag 1$
$a = 1+a/5+b/5+3s/5 \tag 2$
$b=1+a/5+c/5+3s/5 \tag 3$
$c = 1+a/5+d/5+3s/5 \tag 4$
$d = 1+a/5+3s/5 \tag 5$

which yields an [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s+%3D+1%2Ba%2F5%2B4s%2F5%2C+a+%3D+1%2Ba%2F5%2Bb%2F5%2B3s%2F5%2C+b%3D1%2Ba%2F5%2Bc%2F5%2B3s%2F5%2C+c+%3D+1%2Ba%2F5%2Bd%2F5%2B3s%2F5%2C+d+%3D+1%2Ba%2F5%2B3s%2F5) $3125$

Comment: You might consider defining $s$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ and expounding on the system of equations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Will my simulation match your answer?

Comment: @MarkViola: I have expounded a bit on the system of equations

Comment: @stats_noob: From what I can see, your averages don't match mine. As I am not a programmer, I can't comment on your simulation. I have used what is known as First Step Analysis using the Markov property that the next state depends only on the present state. [ Note that states have been defined differently for the two problems according to the requirements.]

Comment: @true blue anil: I only went through your answer to problem one carefully but I still don't see how the equations are coming about. For example, with the first equation , where do you get the 1/5 and 4/5 ? It seems like you are using a discrete uniform distribution but stats_noob has probabilities in his matrix. Should they not be getting used somewhere ?

Comment: @markleeds: I have added a para at the beginning to clarify that this is a demonstration of one particular solution process with uniform probabilities of $\frac15$ for moving from one state to another. With varying probabilities, computerisation would be needed.

Comment: I think you misunderstood question 2. You need to get the exact sequence 12345, i.e. 122345 doesn't work. (In the question he specifies "visit all cities in order for the first time (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5)".) So it can't remain in its current state for b,c,d. Also, with your version of the problem, I think in the last equation (d=...), the last 1*1/5 should be 0 because it's already the final state. If all probabilities are 1/5, my result is 1599 for your version, and 3214 for the original version. Using the specific probabilities provided in the question, I got 353.16 for your version.

Comment: @true blue anil: Thanks. I understand now that your solution was just an example where the probabilities were what you said they were.

Comment: @YiJiang:[1] Interpretation of second problem could be straight $12345$, but it is up to OP to clarify, I raised the point in the Note. [2] Thanks for pointing out the discrepancy in the last equation, but  even then I get a different answer, I have provided a computation link.

Comment: @trueblueanil Oh, that's because you're using a third interpretation of the description. I.e, in my comment above, I allowed 122345 but not 121345, but you allow it. But in that case... shouldn't the probability of transition from state 1-2 to 1-2 be 2/5? So b=1+2b/5+2s/5+c/5, c=1+3c/5+s/5+d/5, d=1+4d/5.

Comment: @YiJiang: I have now added a PS solving for a straight $12345$ . The answer I get is $3125$

Comment: @YiJiang: I have cleaned up the answer, coming round to the view that the wording implies a *straight* $12345$ in the sequence.

Comment: Yeah now that's right. But since the initial state is randomly chosen, there's 1/5 chance that it starts from 1. So it should be 4/5 s + 1/5 a, which makes it 3124. (Not 3214 in my previous comment, it was a typo when I copied the answer. XD )

Comment: @YiJiang;  That is true, but starting from "nothing achieved" gives such a beautiful answer: $5^5$ that I retained it. Anyway, by now OP has enough grist for the mill, can choose and  make minor adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to has the typical solution to problems like this. Here, you just need to identify the states. The states are NOT exactly the cities, they depend on the problem.

Let's look at Problem 2 first, since it's easier to solve. What's the final state of the problem? There is no absorbing state in your original Markov process, but there is one in the problem, which is, all 5 cities have been visited in order, 12345. Let's say the state is $s_{15}$. What are the other states? Apparently, the previous state must be 1234. let's denote that by $s_{14}$. There must also be $s_{13},s_{12}$. If we roll a 1, we are back to state 1, so there should be $s_1$. And if we roll a 2~5 when we are not at the state whose sequence is right before that, we go back to the starting states $s_2$ to $s_5$.

Now there are 9 states, $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5,s_{12},s_{13},s_{14},s_{15}$. The transitions are,

$s_i\rightarrow s_j=p_{ij}, i\geq2,j\geq2$ (transition within states 2,3,4,5),

$s_i\rightarrow s_1=p_{i1}, i\geq2$ (transition into state 1 from states 2,3,4,5),

$s_1\rightarrow s_{12}=p_{12}$ (enters state 12 from state 1),

$s_1\rightarrow s_i=p_{1i},i\geq3$ (goes back to states 3,4,5 from state 1)

$s_{12}\rightarrow s_{13}=p_{23}$ (12 -> 123),

$s_{12}\rightarrow s_i=p_{2i},i\in\{1,2,4,5\}$ (goes back to states 1,2,4,5)

...

Now, we can use the expectation method. Let's denote $E_k$ as the expectation of the number of steps to transit into state $s_{15}$ from state $s_k$.
Apparently we have $E_{15}=0$.

Let's write the equations for the other states. Using $s_1$ as an example, if we are in state $s_1$, take one step, we may end up in any of the states $s_1,s_3,s_4,s_5$, or advance to $s_{12}$. So the equation for expectation is,

$E_1=1+p_{12}E_{12}+p_{11}E_1+p_{13}E_3+p_{14}E_4+p_{15}E_5$

We can get the other 7 equations similarly. (We don't need one for $E_{15}$ because it's just zero.) Now we have 8 equations of 8 variables, we just need to solve this system of linear equations. Since we randomly select an initial state, the result should be $\frac{1}{5}(E_1+E_2+E_3+E_4+E_5)$.

Here's the solution found using python:

```
import numpy as np
p11,p12,p13,p14,p15=0.08692491, 0.23827784, 0.12361982, 0.2669061, 0.28427129
p21,p22,p23,p24,p25=0.01841313, 0.21345092, 0.36070003, 0.2228803, 0.18455562
p31,p32,p33,p34,p35=0.34626521, 0.16405558, 0.24520376, 0.2072284, 0.03724707
p41,p42,p43,p44,p45=0.36424312, 0.09961467, 0.01702542, 0.1327401, 0.38637668
p51,p52,p53,p54,p55=0.22968745, 0.17888838, 0.16538491, 0.2567298, 0.16930943
a = np.array([
    [1-p11,0,-p13,-p14,-p15,-p12,0,0],
    [-p21,1-p22,-p23,-p24,-p25,0,0,0],
    [-p31,-p32,1-p33,-p34,-p35,0,0,0],
    [-p41,-p42,-p43,1-p44,-p45,0,0,0],
    [-p51,-p52,-p53,-p54,1-p55,0,0,0],
    [-p21,-p22,0,-p24,-p25,1,-p23,0],
    [-p31,-p32,-p33,0,-p35,0,1,-p34],
    [-p41,-p42,-p43,-p44,0,0,0,1]])
b = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print(x)
print((x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4])/5)
```

Output:

```
[683.47362743 688.36636677 687.05320945 687.07851411 687.55784906
 668.50927682 632.00167551 421.42219508]
686.705913364849
```

Problem 1 can be solved in a similar fashion, except that the states are different. The absorbing state should be something like {12345}, and the other states should be the set of states that we have already visited. That gives $2^5-1$ states. But that doesn't seem to be enough, since we can't tell the transition probability from, say, {13} to {135}, because we don't know if we transit from 1 to 5 or from 3 to 5. We can do that only if the probabilities are the same.

So, I think the states should be, {current city,{visited cities}}. Now we have $\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}=n2^{n-1}$ states, 80 for $n=5$. The rest is pretty much the same, we write the system of equations for the expectations and solve it. It gets prohibitively difficult for large $n$, since the number of states grows exponentially with $n$. Apparently we can combine similar states so the number is linear with $n$ if the transition probabilities are all the same, but we can't do that if they are different. I wonder if there's a better way to solve it in this case...

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! It looks your analysis/simulation matches the results of my simulations?